# Division by zero and CASE WHEN function

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table as such:

```
|Date |Type |MetricA|MetricB|
|01-01|House|0      |500    |
|01-01|Paid |1      |1000   |
|01-01|Paid |1      |4000   |
|02-01|House|0      |3000   |
|02-01|Paid |10     |13000  |
|02-01|House|0      |5000   |
|02-01|Paid |5      |10000  |
|02-01|Paid |1      |1500   |
```

I want to calculate a 3rd metric (1000*MetricA / MetricB), and I also want MetricB split up per type, so that my final table looks like this:

```
|Date |Metric_House|Metric_Paid|MetricA|NewMetric
|01-01|500         |5000       |2      |0.40
|02-01|8000        |24500      |16     |0.653061224
```

(I hope the table structure makes sense, otherwise I can refer you to a screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2uRa.png)

I figured out how to properly write the Metric_House, Metric_Paid,MetricA column, but I am struggling to write the NewMetric.

Sometimes MetricB == 0, then I can get divide by 0. I can write a case function, but then I run into aggregated summation trouble. I have spent hours trying write a query for this and I just can not figure it out :(
I tried this:

```
func.sum(case([((i.c.metricb) != 0, 1000*func.sum(i.c.metrica)/i.c.metricb)], else_=0))
```

Which is SQLAlchemy (Python layer over SQL), but it basically is:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN METRIC != 0 THEN 1000*SUM(METRICA)/SUM(METRICB) ELSE 0
```

I get a nested error after that query.

I am working in a Python framework, and when I ignore the NewMetric column in the query and just add it afterwards with a simple list function, I did it in a few minutes. But I rather have the data processed within SQL rather than outside.
What would be the best way of writing this query? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is what I have working:

```
stmt = select([i.c.date,
cast(func.sum(case([(
i.c.type != 'House', i.c.metricb)], else_=0)), 
Integer).label('metric_paid'),
cast(func.sum(case([(
i.c.type == 'House', i.c.metricb)], else_=0)),                            
Integer).label('metric_house'),
cast(func.sum(i.c.metrica), Float).label('metrica')]).group_by(
i.c.date).order_by(asc(i.c.date))
```

Now here's what I tried (adding this extra expression):

```
case([(sum(i.c.metricb) != 0, 
1000*sum(i.c.metrica)/sum(i.c.metricb))], else_=0)])
```

NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression

```
func.sum(case([(i.c.metricb!= 0, 
1000*func.sum(i.c.metrica)/func.sum(i.c.metricb))], else_=0))
```

(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) aggregate function calls cannot be nested LINE 1: ...i.metricb != 0) THEN (1000 * sum(i...

Some more trial and error:

```
case([(and_(func.sum(i.c.metricb) != 0, (i.c.type) != 'House'), 1000*func.sum(i.c.metrica)/func.sum(i.c.metricb))])
```

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "type" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

But I do not want the type column in the group by clause, would that not produce erroneous results

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions in the select list to pick each "type". And another case to avoid division by zero.

Comment: "I get a nested error after that query." what does that mean? Surely the interpreter raises an exception and shows you a stacktrace, you should provide this in your question.

Comment: Thanks jarlh for the answer. I use a group by for date. What else would I need to group? The error I get, Giacomo, is ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) aggregate function calls cannot be nested
LINE 1: ...i.metricb != 0) THEN (1000 * sum(i...

Comment: You have effectively `SUM(SUM())` and so you get the error. Nothing to do with the CASE. Please produce a [mcve], or in other words include relevant parts of relevant models/tables and the actual query statement you're using. The Python construction does not match the SQL you've presented. Also include the traceback in the question. You've tagged this [tag:mysql], yet the traceback snippet hints at Postgresql...

Comment: Woops, you are correct, I am working in postgresql, not mysql; I have changed this in the tagging, apologies. I also edited the original question and provided the statements I'm using. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, the following works:

```
WITH mytable AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('2018-01-01', 'House', 0, 500),
            ('2018-01-01', 'Paid', 1, 1000),
            ('2018-01-01', 'Paid', 1, 4000),
            ('2018-01-02', 'House', 0, 3000),
            ('2018-01-02', 'Paid', 10, 13000),
            ('2018-01-02', 'House', 0, 5000),
            ('2018-01-02', 'Paid', 5, 10000),
            ('2018-01-02', 'Paid', 1, 1500)
    ) AS t(date, type, metric_a, metric_b)
)
-- you dont need the above CTE, it is there just for testing in place of your table; use just the select below
SELECT
    date,
    sum(metric_b) FILTER (WHERE type = 'House') AS metric_house,
    sum(metric_b) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Paid') AS metric_paid,
    sum(metric_a) AS metric_a,
    CASE
        WHEN sum(metric_b) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Paid') > 0
            THEN round(1000.0 * sum(metric_a) / sum(metric_b) FILTER (WHERE type = 'Paid'), 4)
        ELSE 0
    END AS new_metric
FROM mytable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

This gives:

```
| date       | metric_house | metric_paid | metric_a | new_metric | 
|------------|--------------|-------------|----------|------------| 
| 2018-01-01 | 500          | 5000        | 2        | 0.4        | 
| 2018-01-02 | 8000         | 24500       | 16       | 0.6531     |
```

Also, your definition of metric_new was unclear. Based on the results you posted, you actually don't want to divide by the whole metric_b, but by just the "Paid" part of it.

Comment: Hi Joe. Thanks so much for answering this. Unfortunately I have not been able to get it to work. I get a syntax error when I try this: ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "("
LINE 18:     sum(metricb) FILTER (WHERE type....... EDIT: I am running postgresql 9.3, and it seems this feature has been introduced in 9.4.

Comment: EDIT: I am running postgresql 9.3, and it seems this feature has been introduced in 9.4. I replaced the FILTER statements by CASE WHEN statements and it worked. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hey Captivader, happy to hear that it helped you. So if your issue is solved, please accept this answer so that everyone can see this has been solved.

Comment: I suppose that is SO etiquette? I'm new here. Thanks again.